# A suitable design pattern for similar web service implementations

Tags: c#, web-services, oop, design-patterns, soap

I'm consuming a SOAP web service that creates a separate service point and WSDL for each of its customers. I don't know why the do that. But e.g. if they have two clients A and B, the service designates two different service addresses with different WSDL addresses. These separate WSDLs are 90% the same objects and same functions but some of them are different based on the type of the customer. Therefore the created objects are eventually not the same even though they work exactly the same way.

So in order to fetch the correct service, I store the name of the customer somewhere on a table ("A" or "B") and my program has to know which customer its dealing with every run. I don't want to have different programs for each customer. I just want my program to get the customer name and based on that understand which model and which controller functions it will use.

**What is the design pattern(s) that will help me facilitate this issue?**
Chances are, in the future there will be an additional customer, so I want my code to be as loosely-coupled as it gets.

I have always wanted to use design patterns correctly in my code so I guess it's time to do so. Should I use a *Strategy Pattern*? Can you briefly explain what is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use two design patterns in your case. The first one would be the [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern). Use the facade pattern to simplify the interface of the web services your application has to deal with. Make sure you only need to change the implementation of the facade when the webservice contract changes. Convert the objects from the service into objects under your control and call functions with names and parameters that fit your domain and abstraction level.

The second design pattern would be the [Adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). In your case, you should determine if you can decide on a common interface for both web services. So, if the 10% difference between the two services can be converted into one interface (of objects and/or functions) you use in your application.

The facade would use adapters to convert the 10% difference into common objects and functions. After that, the facade uses the common objects and functions, as well as the other 90% of the web services, to supply a proper abstraction layer for your application.

If there are additional customers in the future, you'll most likely only need to add or modify an adapter.